# Using a variable within AngularJS 1.5 ngClass

Tags: angularjs, ng-class

I'm using AngularJS 1.5.x and I have a dynamic class passed through which I want to put into an ng-class

Here is what current is broken

```
<td id="name-{{ $index }}" ng-class="{{{result['class']}}: true}">
```

where result['class'] is a dynamic name within the hash which I'm repeating over in my list.

Error

```
angular.js?body=1:14200 Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token '[' is unexpected, expecting [}] at column 8 of the expression [{result['class']] starting at [['class']].
```

NOTE: I'm using ng-class as I want to add an expression on the right so I cannot use the standard 'class'

Answer (score 0):

You can use ternary operator for this.

```
<td id="name-{{ $index }}" ng-class="someExpression ? result['class'] : ''">
```

Where `someExpression` is property on $scope.